# XML date/time formatting in Java

Tags: java, date, time, decode

I'm creating a program in Java that alerts me of Earthquakes in Japan, based around an [online API](http://api.quake.twiple.jp/quake/index.xml) that's formatted in XML.

The output date/time from said API seems to be some sort of jumbled mess, and i'm unsure how I could decode this into a readable format.

Would anyone happen to know a good way to decode this into a readable format in Java?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: What is the output?  Have an example?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/).  My guess is the `eq_date` is the number of seconds since some fixed point in time

Comment: Looking up the values with http://www.epochconverter.com/, it looks like it's a Unix timestamp. You should be able to convert this with the standard date functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

To convert it to a date:

- Multiply by 1000 to convert to milliseconds
- Create a new `Date` with it
- Format the date

Resulting code:

```
long millis = seconds * 1000;
Date date = new Date(millis);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `eq_date` in the XML response is standard epoch so you could simply use that value in a Date object like this

```
var time = new Date(quake.eq_date);
console.log(time.toString());
```

You could also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to help with formatting the output for presentation.